# Cannot get record by ID already previously obtained

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've tried this code shown below in another project and it works, so problem is surely not in a method responsible for getting data from database by ID. Unfortunately, I wasn't able figure out what causes the problem.

Simplest test case: I initialize MongoDB class with methods to work with database. Then I load every record stored in database using method `LoadRecords()` to collection.

```
// some code
MongoDB db = new MongoDB("People");
List<Person> collection = db.LoadRecords<Person>("Person");

//some code
public List<T> LoadRecords<T>(string table)
{
     var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
     return collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
}
```

That works fine, it gives me collection of every document in table. Now I try to find only one element with, for example, ID of first element from that collection using method `LoadRecordById()`.

```
// some code
Person oneRecord = db.LoadRecordById<Person>("Person", people[0].Id);

// some code
public T LoadRecordById<T>(string table, Guid id)
{
      var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
      var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("ID", id);
      return collection.Find(filter).First();
}
```

My `Person` class is also very simple, only includes a few properties and ID:

```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

It really makes no sense to me, first it gives me every record stored in database (its FirstName, LastName, ID) and then when I want to search one record with the exactly same ID it gave me before, it crashes.

> Result is an unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Debug your code step by step. First see if your `filter` is null or not. If it isn't, see what is returned by `collection.Find(filter)`, before trying to call `First()` on it. This is easily verified by using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`

Comment: To add to what @Sach said, check that you're passing the right `id`. Otherwise, figure out which line output the `Sequence contains no elements` error.